# UIWebview open URL in mobile safari using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview, phaser-framework

So I'm building an HTML5 game using phaser and I have a button that calls a URL in javascript like this:

```
window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
```

This works great on desktop opening in a new window, I'm also able to get it to open in the default browser on an android device via webview as well. But on iOS using a UIWebView in swift I'm using the following code

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

It triggers so yes I have the delegate set, I even have a breakpoint in here so I could look through the properties, and `request.URL` is nowhere to be found. None of these properties have a URL I can use to detect and call mobile safari...

Everything I've found online just says it's only known to work with standard link tags like `<a href="http://google.com">link text</a>` I also tried `document.location.href = "http://google.com";` with no luck. Btw, I did test with `<a href="http://google.com">link text</a>` and this function works, it makes it open in safari. It just doesn't work when the URL is called via Javascript.

Also, `webViewDidStartLoad/webViewDidFinishLoad` both trigger breakpoints when the URL is called yet there is no URL anywhere to be found in any of the properties provided in the webView object...

Any ideas how I can get the delegate functions to play well with with javascript calling the URL? Or any ideas for work arounds? It's just loading the link inside the webview... I just need it to open those links in mobile safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Just make an empty a tag somewhere on your html page that conatins the game content like:

```
<a id="theLink" target="_blank" href="http://google.com"></a>
```

Then "click" it using Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('theLink').click();
```

That used in conjunction with the swift code above is working for me and the game opens the link in safari.

Comment: Does it still work? I try on mine and it doesn't work for me. I want to open default browser if client is detected to be in third party's webview.