# Open website from a iOS 10 webapp in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, uiwebview

I'm stuck on a very annoying problem: I own a website and I need the user to visit it from the native Safari app when on iPhone/iPad with iOS 10.

Problems arise when a third-party webapp (that uses the "embedded version" of the mobile browser) has a link to my website. The user clicks the link but my website is opened *inside* the webapp. It does not open it in an external instance of Safari.

Is there a workaround to open it on Safari? I mean, since I'm not able to change the source code of a given webapp... can I use Javascript on my website for this task?

I've already searched for solutions with many results... but no luck:

- [How to open Safari from a WebApp in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879631/how-to-open-safari-from-a-webapp-in-ios-7)
- [Open a link from web app to new Safari window in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299394/open-a-link-from-web-app-to-new-safari-window-in-ios-8)
- [UIWebview open URL in mobile safari using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853020/uiwebview-open-url-in-mobile-safari-using-javascript)
- [iOS UIWebView app opens link in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476772/ios-uiwebview-app-opens-link-in-safari)

None of them works. And if you are curious, the most problematic app I'm talking about is... Instagram. When the users click on a link in that app, it does not open Safari but it stays in an internal webview. *Damn*!

Comment: I don't think you have control over that unless you can modify the third-party webapp.

Answer (score -1):

Simply using ion button with href and your able to open link

```
      <ion-button  *ngIf="user.facebook_url" href="{{ user.facebook_url }}" target="_blank" 
      fill="clear" size="small" color="light" class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
```

Comment: This is not even close to right answer. You're providing ionic specific code, and that too, doesn't work. All it may do is, open the link in a new tab. In no way it will open the link in safari.